# Turning a fixed width hex string encoding a fixed width signed integer into the integer in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 5 digit (20 bit) hex string that encodes a signed integer in twos complement. Is there a compact, simple way to extract the integer in Python?

Comment: please explain more and submit a minimal working example so that others don't have to guess what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(s, 16)    # get the unsigned value of your hex string
if n >= 2**19:    # if sign bit is set...
    n -= 2**20    # ...make it negative
```